# what is the compatible oauth1 version for Dart SDK version is 3.1.3?

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication

I am trying to use oauth1 in my flutter application. i use oauth1: ^1.0.6 in pubsec.yml.  there is an issue....
"The current Dart SDK version is 3.1.3.
Because nextshop depends on oauth1 >=1.0.2 <2.0.0-nullsafety.0 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.
The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.58.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety. "
....
what is the compatible oauth1 version for Dart SDK version is 3.1.3 ?[image]

i am expecting compatible oauth1 version for dart sdk version 3.1.3

Comment: You can check all versions here https://pub.dev/packages/oauth1/versions . As you can see only the latest one 2.0.0 supports null safety so you could try that one. But as you also can see that package was last updated 2 years ago so I don't know if it's really that great of a package

Answer (score 0):

2.0.0 is the version with the null safety support

[Here](https://pub.dev/packages/oauth1/changelog) you can fund more information.

Btw, this package is without upate during the last 2 years maybe not a good choice